# I have a NullPointerException report in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, nullpointerexception, struts

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<package name="backpower" namespace="/backpower" extends="struts-default">
    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
    <!-- backup battery manager -->
    <action name="backpower" class="com.cps.backpower.action.BackpowerAction">
        <result name="addBattery">/WEB-INF/views/backpower/info/addBattery.jsp</result>
        <result name="editBattery">/WEB-INF/views/backpower/info/editBattery.jsp</result>
        <result>/WEB-INF/views/backpower/info/list.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**`add.jsp`:**

```
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button name="method:save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            save
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">
            reset
        </button>
    </div>
```

**my `BackpowerAction` class**

```
public class BackpowerAction extends BaseManageAction{

private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
public BackpowerService backpowerService;
public PaginationSupport backpowerPagination;
public PageTip pageTip;
public BackpowerInfo backpowerInfo;
public Long id;


public String execute() throws Exception{
    return search();
}

public String search(){
    String hql="from BackpowerInfo where 1=1";
    backpowerPagination=backpowerService.getPage(hql,getPageNo(),getPageSize());
    return SUCCESS;
}

public void setBackpowerInfo(BackpowerInfo backpowerInfo){
    this.backpowerInfo=backpowerInfo;
}

public String add(){
    return "addBattery";
}

public String save() {
    if (backpowerInfo.getId() == null) {
        try {
            backpowerService.save(backpowerInfo);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return add();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            backpowerService.update(backpowerInfo.getId(),backpowerInfo.getName(),backpowerInfo.getLocation(),backpowerInfo.getManager());
            pageTip.setOk(true);
            pageTip.setTip("修改用户信息成功");
            return search();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pageTip.setOk(false);
            pageTip.setTip("修改用户信息失败");
            return edit();
        }
    }

}

public String edit() {
    backpowerInfo=backpowerService.findById(getId());

    return "editBattery";
}

public String del() throws Exception {
    try {
        backpowerService.delete(getId());
        pageTip.setOk(true);
        pageTip.setTip("删除成功");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pageTip.setOk(false);
        pageTip.setTip("删除失败");
    }
    return search();
}

public BackpowerInfo getBackpowerInfo(){
    return backpowerInfo;
}




public PaginationSupport getBackpowerPagination(){

    return backpowerPagination;
}

public void setBackpowerPagination(PaginationSupport backpowerPagination){
    this.backpowerPagination=backpowerPagination;
}

public BackpowerService getBackpowerService(){
    return backpowerService;
}

public void setBackpowerService(BackpowerService backpowerService){
    this.backpowerService=backpowerService;
}

public PageTip getPageTip(){
    return pageTip;
}

public void setPageTip(PageTip pageTip){
    this.pageTip=pageTip;
}

public long getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id){
    this.id=id;
}
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   com.cps.backpower.action.BackpowerAction.save(BackpowerAction.java:39)

When I click save button on the web page, it gives Struts2 problem report, where am I wrong, how should I correct it?

Comment: Could you please post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Could you post the struts errors? The nullpointer is probably thrown in the *backpowerService.update(backpowerInfo.getId(),backpowerInfo.getName(),backpowerInfo.getLocation(),backpowerInfo.getManager());* as you do not check for there values.

Comment: What code is at line 39 of BackpowerAction.java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name of the instance object of the model `BackpowerInfo` in `BackpowerAction` should be same with the name used in `add.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

I think `backpowerInfo` is null in your code.

You haven't populated or instantiated it before calling getters.

Comment: the NullPointerException thrown in the backpowerAction.save() method,line 39 is the first line of save() method.You are right Ankur,backpowerInfo is null when call save() method,but I don't know how instantiated it before calling getters?@FlorisVelleman,@orique,@AleksandrM

Comment: @hkk: just write backpowerInfo = new BackpowerInfo();  to instantiate it.

Comment: :but I want Spring framework to instantiate it.And below are log of tomcat,all the fields i want to submit have the same problem:

        WARN [http-8888-1] OgnlValueStack.warn(49) | Error setting expression 'backpowerinfo.manager' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1637de8'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "manager", [Ljava.lang.String;@1637de8)

Answer (score 0):

I thought `backpowerService` is `null`, after counting lines in your code. You should inject service before use.

I saw there's a setter for `backpowerService` but it should be called before any action is executed. I don't know which way you instantiate a `BackpowerService` bean, which container and DI. But you don't do it with interceptor, as your configuration doesn't reflect it.

My suggestions is to use some DI framework and place your service bean there and use `@Inject` on setter or field to inject the service as a dependency, i.e.

```
@Inject
public void setBackpowerService(BackpowerService backpowerService){
    this.backpowerService=backpowerService;
}
```

Comment: my BackpowerService is configured in applicationContext.xml as below
    
    <bean id="backpowerService"
    class="com.cps.backpower.service.impl.BackpowerServiceImp>
    <property name="backpowerDao" ref="backpowerDao" />
    </bean>

I think it's right,so I don't know why backpowerInfo hasn't been instantiated?